# Which Oracle index is best to choose 

Tags: performance, indexing, oracle11g

I am having a table that has 5 million record. The primary key of this table is created in sequence. My question is which index to create for best performance?

1. B-Tree Index (default)
2. (Range) Partitioned Indexes
3. Or any other?

Considered I am going to use SELECT operation most of the time

Comment: Depends on the queries you run. Just try them, look at the explain plan, and pick what's best.

Comment: It dependes on the most frequent and most important operations (queries, updates, inserts etc.). The question cannot be answered without more information about the intended use.

Comment: Right, Thats what i am going to do as a next step. But there has to be some theoretical explanation isn't?

Comment: I have update my question to use "Select" operation

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this questions is downgraded? whats wrong in it?

Answer (score 0):

B-Tree is the default.  We have tables with one billion rows with B-tree indexes. OLTP systems almost always use B-tree for everything.  The only time you consider alternate index types is because of special considerations. For example, a highly redundant data set(low cardinality): like an index on a column that contains only Y or N characters, may benefit from a bit-map index. At least in terms of resources.

Bitmaps are favored often for Data Warehouse applications.  Other approaches are partitioned tables where a single physical data file has all of one single common column.  This eliminates having to read across all of the files in a tablespace to run a report. Ex: the End of Month data for A/R.